# VBA data structure for performing different analysis

Tags: vba, excel

Is there some kind of data structure I could use for the following analysis? Visually, this is what my data is like in Excel

```
Condition ID       Item1        Item2        Item3        ...
Ex A      1        A            B            C            ...
Ex B      2       
Ex C      3        C     
Ex A      5        D            A    
Ex C      5
```

Each row corresponds to an ID, and there can be multiple same IDs. Condition is a string (there can also be multiple same Conditions seen  above) associated with any # of Items (could be none and could also repeat).

Functions I want to perform are things like determining the total # of unique Items among all Conditions, seeing which Items appear most/least often, which combo of Condition and singular Item is most frequent, and the breakdown of IDs per Condition.

Would the best way be to just brute force each of the Questions I want to answer? For example for the first part of finding all unique targets, should I just loop through every row's cell until the Value in the cell = "", adding each item to a Collection unless it already exists in the collection? I feel like doing that and the other analysis I want to perform would take too long this way in terms of coding and run time maybe?

Comment: Perhaps you could forget about VBA and use a [pivot table](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html). In VBA, a dictionary would seem to be natural.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out how to do one part (counting # of instances of each item) using a dictionary

```
For row = 1 To lastRow
    For col = 1 To lastCol
        If arrayOfValues(row, col) <> "" Then
            If rawString.Exists(arrayOfValues(row, col)) Then
                rawString.Item(arrayOfValues(row, col)) = rawString.Item(arrayOfValues(row, col)) + 1
            Else
                rawString.Add arrayOfValues(row, col), 1
            End If
            Debug.Print arrayOfValues(row, col), rawString(arrayOfValues(row, col))
        End If
    Next col
Next row
```